# update function doesn't save

Tags: php, sql, database

I am creating a plugin for wordpress. With this plugin, you can insert some data and images in the database.

when you install the plugin it creates its own database table.

Here's my problem:
When I want to update, it doesn't save the updated fields. 
I have worked with `$this->getTableName()` everywhere, but in the update function it doesn't work that way..

this is the code where i think the problem is in:

```
if (isset($_FILES['afbeelding']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['afbeelding']['name']))
    {
    $this->upload($_FILES['afbeelding']);
    $query = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE  " . $this->getTableName() . " SET `naam` = '%s', `level` = '%s', `beschrijving` = '%s', `afbeelding` = '%s' " . "WHERE
              `wp_ivs_canvas_tabel`.`id` =%d;", $input_array['naam'], $input_array['level'], $input_array['beschrijving'], $_FILES['afbeelding']['name'], $input_array['id']);
    }
  else
    {

    // no images selected
    // do this

    $query = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE " . $this->getTableName() . " SET `naam` = '%s', `level` = '%s', `beschrijving` = '%s' " . "WHERE
              `wp_ivs_canvas_tabel`.`id` =%d;", $input_array['naam'], $input_array['level'], $input_array['beschrijving'], $input_array['id']);
    }
```

Comment: You're preparing the statement, but not executing it.

Comment: yeah i do but i think the problem is in this piece of code, so i cut the code..

Comment: i think, after "WHERE. that i have to change wp_ivs_canvas_tabel into $this->getTableName() or something.. but that doens't work

Comment: Which database? It might require COMMIT for example. Otherwise please check, that there is data to update, I mean WHERE filter is passed.

Comment: i just need to know how i have to change wp_ivs_canvas_tabel to . $this->getTableName() .